# TanStack queries inadvertently entering "paused" state

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tanstackreact-query

I am having a problem both deving locally and in production where stochastically users will enter a state where certain queries are `paused`. The queries enter the `paused` state from initial page load, so the paused queries never actually fire off any requests they just forever sit in a `paused` state as shown in the screenshot below.

As per the [TanStack Query docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/network-mode), I understand that this will happen when a user loses network connection. What is weird here is that the page loads and a user can take actions on the page, so seemingly the network is connected for all of the app except for a small subset of my queries. Once it appears, this bug does not go away by refreshing the page, navigating pages, logging out/back in in the app, hard refreshing, hard quitting, etc. It is literally only fixed by restarting your computer, which seems absolutely crazy.

My queryClient is setup as such:

```
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});
```

If I update the queryClient to be this, this fixes it, as none of my queries will be in the `paused` state anymore:

```
export const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: Infinity,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      networkMode: "always"
    },
  },
});
```

My app is a Next.js (13.0.3), React (18.2.0), TanStack (4.22.0) application. I saw this happen about once or twice deving locally in the past few weeks, and just saw it in production today.

I believe I have fixed the problem, so my questions that remain are:

Has anyone seen this before/understand why this is a problem? This fix makes sense, but it doesn't help me understand the fundamental problem of why this is happening in the first place?